# Linq to SQL and SQL Server auto-increment field

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have table with several fields, one of them is Id auto-increment/primary field. Is it possible to read new record Id field value after inserting new record using Linq to SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the Id property will be set automatically when you call `SubmitChanges`. Example:

```
var customer = new Customer();
Console.WriteLine(customer.Id); // 0

context.Customers.InsertOnSubmit(customer); // Attach it to the context
context.SubmitChanges();

Console.WriteLine(customer.Id); // 1
```